# How to execute command in DataGrip

Tags: datagrip

I'm using DataGrip 2019.2, and I'd like to execute a command (PostgreSQL) such as `\h RELEASE SAVEPOINT` to get more information about a commmand.

I've tried using the `console` feature and it complains this is invalid syntax. How do I execute commands such as this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for now. Please follow and vote for the ticket.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-4660